# How to create a summary view of Master/Detail Tables using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two (simplified) tables/classes set up like this:

```
public class OrderHeader
{
    public OrderHeader()
    {
        Details = new HashSet<OrderDetail>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> Details { get; set; }
}

public class OrderDetail
{
    [Key]
    public int DetailId { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int QuantityOrdered { get; set; }
    public int QuantityShipped { get; set; }
    public int QuantityRemaining { get; set; }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TransactionId")]
    public virtual OrderHeader Header { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to create a view to return:

1. The `TransactionId`
2. A count of all details by `OrderHeader` as column `Number of Details`
3. A count of details by `OrderHeader` where `QuantityRemaining` equals zero as columnn `Completed`
4. A count of details by `OrderHeader` named `Partially Shipped` where `QuantityShipped` is greater than zero but less than `QuantityOrdered`

I have tried querying both the `OrderHeader` and the `OrderDetails` tables and trying to make sub queries for each column I wanted but I wind up getting multiple lines with the same `TransactionId`. And when I use the `DISTINCT` select the numbers are off from what I know to be correct.

While admitting this is utterly pitiful, I can get a partial but accurate result set with only two columns:

```
    SELECT
        TransactionId,
        COUNT(*) AS [Number of Details]
    FROM OrderDetails
    GROUP BY TransactionID
```

But I can not get it working with the other two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
SELECT
  TransactionId,
  COUNT(*) AS [Number of Details],
  Sum(CASE WHEN QuantityRemaining = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Completed],
  Sum(CASE WHEN QuantityShipped > 0 AND QuantityShipped < QuantityOrdered THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Partially Shipped]
FROM OrderDetails
GROUP BY TransactionID
```

Comment: Thank you @jonathan for a quick and concise answer. It worked just as simply as you wrote it.